# Como hacer un filtrado de datos dinamico con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lo que necesito es que alguien me ayude con un problema que tengo. Resulta que el usuario tiene que ingresar el nombre de un *pais* (este nombre se encuentra en un archivo `paises.csv`), luego muestra en pantalla las provincias que este *pais* contiene(estas estan en el mismo csv). Esto logro hacerlo correctamente pero mi idea es que a las provincias del *pais* que usuario ingreso las vaya a buscar al archivo (provincias.csv) y muestre todas las columnas de las provincias que pertenecen al pais que el usario ingreso. Adjunto toda la data.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("paises.csv", index_col=['Numero'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv", index_col=['Numero'])
usuario = input("Ingrese el nombre del pais que desea:")
lista = df1[df1["Nombre"].str.contains(usuario.lower())]
lista_de_provincias = lista[['Nombre','provincias']]
print(lista_de_provincias)
```

Hasta ahí el programa funciona.

**archivo paises.csv**

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,argentina,ar1|ar2|ar3|ar4|ar5
Pais2,chile,ch1|ch2|ch3|ch4
Pais3,brasil,br1|br2|br3|br4
```

**archivo provincias.csv**

```
Numero,Nombre,contagiosTotales,contagiosDiarios,contagiosActivos,muertesTotales,muertesDiarias,vacunasAplicadas,vacunasSinAplicar,vacunasTotales
ar1,ciudad autonoma de buenos aires,687000,2845,178000,9302,36,1011854,1608,1013462
ar2,santa fe,2,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar3,c,4900,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar4,d,9340,92,12,12,12,12,12,12
ch1,e,300,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ch2,f,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar5,g,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
```

Lo que necesito es que si el usuario ingresa argentina vaya al archivo `provincias.csv` y muestre las provincias que corresponden. Como a argentina se le asigno `ar1|ar2|ar3|ar4|ar5` tiene que mostrar todos los datos de esas provincias(los datos que se encuentran en *provincias.csv*)

Comment: Les deseo a todos un buen fin de semana. Gracias desde ya a todos los que me ayuden

Comment: me haces abrir el VS otra vez >: v

Comment: jajajaja gracias capooo sos el uno de stackoverflow

Comment: En realidad si, pero de la semana https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/week/es-stackoverflow/2021-05-24

Comment: fua te felicito amigo, alto capo!!

Comment: Gracias, ahora publico la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice una modificación, pues al leer los archivos haces `pd.read_csv("provincias.csv", index_col=['Numero'])` donde le indicas que la columna `Numero` sea el indice y pues eso dificulta elegir los datos en base a eso, por lo que no puse eso.
También hacemos uso de la función `isin()`

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("paises.csv", index_col=['Numero'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv")

# usuario = input("Ingrese el nombre del pais que desea:")
usuario = "argentina" # es para pruebas, puedes dejar el inpput
#obtenemos los datos
lista = df1[df1["Nombre"].str.contains(usuario.lower())]

#obtenemos las provincias
provincias = lista['provincias']

#separamos cada una de las provincias
provincias = [prov.split('|') for prov in provincias][0]
#print(provincias)

#aqui seleccionamos del df2 solo cuando el Numero se encuentra la lista de provincias
lista_de_provincias = df2[df2["Numero"].isin(set(provincias))]
print(lista_de_provincias)
```

`[prov.split('|') for prov in provincias]` es una compresión de lista, que no es mas que un simple ciclo `for` pero *comprimido* que dice que en cada iteración, separara (`split()`) la cadena si encuentra el carácter `|`. En un ciclo for seria algo asi:

```
for prov in provincias:
    nueva_lista = prov.split('|')
print(nueva_lista)
#salida -> [['ar1', 'ar2', 'ar3', 'ar4', 'ar5']]
```

como eso nos devuelve una lista de lista, accedemos al primer elemento con `[0]`, teniendo como resultado

```
['ar1', 'ar2', 'ar3', 'ar4', 'ar5']
```

La funcion `df.isin(values)` lo que haces es verificar si el *DataFrame* (`df`) contiene los valores (`values`) y devuelve lo que coincida con esa condición.
se utiliza `set()` solo para convertir los datos, en este caso no es muy importante, por lo que se puede omitir `df2[df2["Numero"].isin(provincias)]` y el resultado será el mismo.

Teniendo como resultado esto, si ingresamos `"argentina"`

```
  Numero                           Nombre  contagiosTotales  contagiosDiarios  ...
0    ar1  ciudad autonoma de buenos aires            687000              2845  ...              
1    ar2                         santa fe                 2                12  ...              
2    ar3                                c              4900                12  ...              
3    ar4                                d              9340                92  ...              
6    ar5                                g               234                12  ...              

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Gracias christian me sirvio, que significa .split("|") for prov in provincias[0]

Comment: ahora edito la respuesta añdiendo eso

Comment: Graciass. Y si digamos que quisiera sumar los datos de ese pais? Osea que para obtener los contagios totales de ese pais tengo que sumar los contagios totales de las provincias que corresponden a ese pais como hago?

Comment: solo accedes a esa columna y aplicas la función de Python `sum()`, asi `sum(lista_de_provincias["contagiosTotales"])`

Comment: Gracias me estas re salvando jajaja. Ahora si quisiera digamos obtener el pais con mas contagios totales tendria que sumar primero los contagios totales de las provincias que le corresponden a ese pais y luego comparar cual es el mas grande. Obviamente el mas grande lo imprimo en pantalla. Como haria eso?

Comment: Para evitar código redundante y hacer todo en una linea, se usaría una *lambda expression* o expresión lambda, pero esto seria aplicado al *df2* pues este tiene esos datos

Comment: Te sugiero que primero intentes de la forma en que se te ocurra, si no puedes o no obtienes el resultado esperado, hagas tu pregunta, pues eso ya es otra cosa aparte de esta pregunta.